# MVC 5. AddRouteValue method doesn't work with constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

First of all, I need to say that I'm using `T4MVC`. I have such `Action`:

```
public virtual ActionResult List(string slug, string category, String selectedFilters)
```

And route for this `Action`:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductsList", "{slug}/{category}/{selectedFilters}", MVC.Product.List()
                .AddRouteValue("selectedFilters", string.Empty), constraints: new { slug = new ProductListConstraint() });
```

In my project are exist links with such scheme: `/{slug}/{category}`
My route doesn't react on such link. 
But this route (without constraint) works just fine:

```
//routes.MapRoute("ProductsList", "{slug}/{category}/{selectedFilters}", MVC.Product.List()
            //    .AddRouteValue("selectedFilters", string.Empty));
```

Could anyone explain me why and could help to fix it?